# Navigation link to launch HTML 5 Video fullscreen

Tags: html, video

I have a fullscreen background video running in a page using an html5 video tag to play a local hosted video there is a css nav menu running across the top. I want to launch another video fullscreen over the top of the existing video when a user clicks the menu. I have no idea how to do this. The video is running responsively using fitvid.js so I don't need to scale the video in this code. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the background with some Javascript:

```
<script>

   function changeBackground {
      document.getElementsById("nav-Id");
      onclick = "import your background video here"
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. This appears to work for one swap out. However there are several videos iI will need to swap out. Which is why i need to do it by a navigation menu. Each menu item illustrating a choice. Channel, Agencies, Partners etc... I could do it by triggering separate pages but I was wondering whether I could load a video as a background based on a menu choice all within one page, The menu might look like this 
<div class="back"></div><nav>
  <a href="#">Video</a>
  <a href="#">Partners</a>
  <a href="#">Channel</a>
  <a href="#">Agencies</a>
</nav>

Comment: Can you please post all your code on a pen on https://codepen.io so I'll able to check well your code. When you want, replay to me with the link of your pen and I'll answer you!

Comment: And also, if you'd like, you can share the pen with me.

Comment: https://codepen.io/artyom-ivanov/pen/awyyzv this is the menu

Comment: <!-- The initial fullscreen video -->
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline id="myVideo">
  <source src="my url to video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>